# Deep history bottom for backtesting strategy

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I dont have available the deep history bottom on my tradingview backtesting tab. What i have to do to be able to use this feature?

I just dont have the botton available.

Answer (score 1):

deep history testing available only for Premium subscribe.
If you have premium, else better write to sapport